# Inner join tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have SQL table Policy that contains column as PolicyNumber which has value 'CCL-9997-10497' 
and another table PolicyImages which also has column PolicyNumber which has value 'CCL-9997-000010497'

I wanted to inner join both these table on PolicyNumber ?
How can I achieve it ?

Comment: what is the relationship between two tables?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: one to one relationship is there between 2 tables on column PolicyNumber

Comment: You should consider creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this -- it will make helping you much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two tables have different format of PolicyNumber so you need some kind of computation.
I think below query will help you

```
SELECT a.* FROM
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.PolicyNumber = 
Replace(b.PolicyNumber,'-' + right(b.PolicyNumber,charindex('-',REverse(b.PolicyNumber))-1),
'-' + convert(varchar,Convert(Decimal,right(b.PolicyNumber,charindex('-',REverse(b.PolicyNumber))-1)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM Policy 
INNER JOIN PolicyImageq ON Policy.PolicyNumber = PolicyImages.PolicyNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time mistake, then you can do:

```
Policy p join
PolicyImages pi
on p.PolicyNumber = pi.PolicyNumber or
   (p.PolicyNumber = 'CCL-9997-10497' and pi.PolicyNumber =  'CCL-9997-000010497')
```

If this is a formatting issue, then the solution is actually database-specific.

Comment: There are so many PolicyNumbers in both tables .. I need to join them .. I can't hard code PolicyNumbers